# Any way to use one Graph rendering engine (e.g. fdp) for node coordinates, and the use another Graph rendering engine (e.g. dot) for edges?

Tags: python, graphviz, dot

I noticed 'fdp' is generating graphs with very nice node placement for the graph I'm trying to make. However, the edges between nodes are straight lines, and sometimes overlap nodes.

I noticed that 'dot' rendering engine is very good at keeping edges from overlapping until it has no choice to, and even then making the edges distinct by prioritizing crosses only when the directions are not similar so they can be easily identified.

I would like to use fdp to generate my graph's node coordinates, and then use dot to carry out the rest of the work. I was hoping there was a canonical or at least existing solution out there.

If this is not possible I'm also wondering why.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use different rendering engines for nodes and edges separately. But your problem still has a solve:

Every graph type in Graphviz has a special attribute: [splines](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:splines). You can set `splines=curved` or `splines=polyline` in your file so `fdp` will use them and will try to avoid annoying overlapping.

```
graph {
    splines=polyline;
    a -- b;
    b -- c;
    a -- c;
    d -- c;
    e -- c;
    e -- a;
}
```

P.S. Many layouts use both nodes and edges info to calculate node positions and edge shapes so they are used as-is. It is VERY rare case when someone needs one algorithm for nodes and another for edges so nobody implements it. Maybe it is possible with some dirty-dirty hacks, but it should not be used anyway.